# Beacon ranging vs BLE scanning

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, beacon

I was trying to understand the difference between Beacon Ranging and BLE Scanning. From what I understand, beacon ranging uses BLE scanning to find the beacons. On top of that it calculates proximity of beacons using the signal strength(which I do not need). I just need to detect the beacons(similar to beacon monitoring). I am not using beacon monitoring because of the Always permission requirement in IOS. I know that beacon monitoring is highly optimised as compared to ranging, but I wanted to know how ranging compares to BLE scanning.

- Can i use `BLEModule.scanForDevices(UUID)`  in place of `CLLocationManager.startRangingBeacons(region)` to detect beacons? If yes, can I get callbacks in similar fashion when beacon is detected?
- Are there any downsides of doing this in terms of battery performance or detection time, etc.?

  Note that I am willing to make do without proximity information(distance from beacon).

Also, a related question:

- Can beacon monitoring be used in foreground with WhenInUse permission in iOS?(I found mixed views on this in my initial investigation)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use Core Bluetooth scanning to detect an iBeacon. You must use Core Location and monitor a `CLBeaconRegion` to discover iBeacons.

Having discovered a beacon you do not need to range it.

As stated in [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/determining_the_proximity_to_an_ibeacon)

> **Important**
>
> Apps must have always authorization to use region monitoring, and they must be configured with the Location updates background mode to be launched.

Even if you only want beacon notification when your app is in the foreground you must request *always* permission.

Comment: I would add that the primary reason you cannot use BLE scanning is because Apple blocks accessing the scan data payload of BLE packets that are iBeacon frames.  CoreBluetooth actually makes the advertising data appear empty (when in reality it is not.) Apple does this to force you to use CoreLocation.

Comment: @davidgyoung, thanks for the explanation. So I want to do the following in my app: 1. Discover a BLE device using beacon monitoring (or BLE scanning if I dont get the Always permission) 2. Exchange information with the device using GATT. Here the device is intended to be a microcontroller with a BLE chip. Can a BLE chip be configured to advertise both beacons and expose GATT services? Can this be done in the same advertisement packet?

Comment: It sounds like you just want to identify a BLE peripheral that is advertising a GATT service; no need for iBeacon.  There is no easy way to link an iBeacon discovery and a Core Bluetooth peripheral; The UUID of the beacon is just a number you assign and you can't obtain the MAC address of a beacon or a GATT peripheral.

Comment: @Paulw11 - Thanks for the reply. What about beacon ranging vs BLE scanning. i.e. If I want to discover a BLE device from my app, should I advertise beacons from that device and use beacon ranging? Or should I discover the device by advertising its GATT Profile. I ask this because this is for discovering the device from my app and ranging/scanning might continue for more than a day before the user comes in range of the device and device is detected. Will BLE scanning impact battery performance in this case as compared to Beacon ranging?